# Problem using Press-this book marklet

Tags: plugins, errors

When I use the bookmarklet button to test bookmarking . Only some URLs might able to display the post page.For other URLs it is just showing an error:

```
404. The requested page was not found.
```

I have deactivated all the plugins .But problem not solved .I have changed the theme though .

Do any body have Idea on solving this problem?

I am not sure how to solve the problem .I copied the screen shots of error here .

[image]

Comment: I have asked the same question on wordpress forums and Buddypress forums .No reply ! Could any body help me

Comment: Could you give some examples of URLs that don't work? (The original page, and the `wweb.in/wp-admin/press-this.php` page from the pop-up) Does it make a difference whether you selected some text before you clicked the button or not?

Comment: Every URL other than my blog had the problem .I contacted my host's representatives and they said that it was the server problem .They solved the problem by white listing some code on server .How ever I am happy as the problem has been solved .Thanks for help !

Comment: I don't understand that why this small error related to that server issue .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem resolved by my web-host's executives .They said that they had to white list a code on their servers .